# Convert a raw negative rgb int value back to a 3 number rgb value

Tags: java, int, rgb, negative-number

Ok so I'm working on a program that takes in an image, isolates a block of pixels into an array, and then gets each individual rgb value for each pixel in that array.

When I do this

```
//first pic of image
//just a test
int pix = myImage.getRGB(0,0)
System.out.println(pix);
```

It spits out -16106634

I need to get the (R, G, B) value out of this int value

Is there a formula, alg, method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`BufferedImage.getRGB(int x, int y)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29) method always returns a pixel in the `TYPE_INT_ARGB` color model. So you just need to isolate the right bits for each color, like this:

```
int pix = myImage.getRGB(0, 0);
int r = (pix >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (pix >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = pix & 0xFF;
```

If you happen to want the alpha component:

```
int a = (pix >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Alternatively you can use the [`Color(int rgba, boolean hasalpha)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) constructor for convenience (at the cost of performance).

Comment: Cool. Make sure you copied the bit shifts in the right direction... I actually made a typo the first time and fixed it in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
int pix = myImage.getRGB(0,0);
Color c = new Color(pix,true); // true for hasalpha
int red = c.getRed();
int green = c.getGreen();
int blue = c.getBlue();
```