# Programmatically make a color more transparent

Tags: android, colors, transparent

I'm working on a simple bar graph application that uses a static array of colors for divvying out bar colors.  I would like the functionality to either draw bars normally, or slightly transparent.

Is there a way to programmatically adjust a color integer so that it's slightly transparent?  Or will I have to statically define a transparent version of each color and then switch to using these versions whenever I want transparency?

Comment: Have a look at setAlpha http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure...Look at Color and there's a function:

```
static int   argb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue)
```

Return a color-int from alpha, red, green, blue components.

So your RGB values could be static and you just bump the alpha value to get a new transparent version of the color.

Comment: Thanks a ton! For those of you wondering how to get the RGB values from an integer, take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526690/convert-a-raw-negative-rgb-int-value-back-to-a-3-number-rgb-value

Answer (score 134):

If you are using support library, you can use:

```
ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(int color, int alpha);
```

If you are not using support library, one-line solution taken from it's source code is:

```
int res = (color & 0x00ffffff) | (alpha << 24);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It's simpler and setAlphaComponent works very well as long as the alpha int is between 0 and 250.

Comment: I'm_With_Stupid between 0 and 255 to be more precise

Comment: ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent was added to the API (22.1) ~2 years after this question was posted. The whole ColorUtils class has a whole bunch of neat things in it. Anyone stumbling on this thread now would be well served to review it (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils.html)

Comment: This is the only solution answer!

Answer (score 7):

Hi there you could use the:

> android.support.v4.graphics.ColorUtils#setAlphaComponent

note: the alpha here is from 0 to 255 and not % based.

There are also other util methods such contract and luminosity calculations in there.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Try following code

```
int color = (int)Long.parseLong(your_color, 16);
int r = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = (color >> 0) & 0xFF;
```

if color code has alpha then

```
int alpha= (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 3):

From the top answer I created a method to do this:

```
private Android.Graphics.Color AddTransparencyToColour(Android.Graphics.Color color, int transparancy)
{
    return Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(transparancy, color.R, color.G, color.B);
}
```

It's also worth noteing that this can be changed to an extension method like so

```
public static ColorExtensions
{
    public static Android.Graphics.Color AddTransparency(this Android.Graphics.Color color, int transparancy)
    {
        return Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(transparancy, color.R, color.G, color.B);
    }
}
```

In regards to the alpha value, from [MSDN Color.FromArgb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hstcth9(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Remarks**
>
> To create an opaque color, set alpha to 255. To create a
>   semitransparent color, set alpha to any value from 1 through 254.

Answer (score 2):

I use extension functions.

```
fun Int.withAlpha(@IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) alpha: Int): Int {
    return (alpha shl 24) or (this and 0xFFFFFF)
}
```

Also possible with `ColorUtils`

```
ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(color, alpha)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a colour helper which returns same colour with applied alpha. - *Lets say you want to change visibility from 0.0 to 1.0 (double)*

```
 val originalColour: Int = primaryColor
 val generatedColor = ColorUtil.generateTransparentColor(originalColour, 0.5)
 view.setBackgroundColor(generatedColor)
```

Create a colour generator helper

```
object ColorUtil {
  fun generateTransparentColor(color: Int, alpha: Double?): Int {
    val defaultAlpha = 255 // (0 - Invisible / 255 - Max visibility)
    val colorAlpha = alpha?.times(defaultAlpha)?.roundToInt() ?: defaultAlpha
    return ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(color, colorAlpha)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those in the compose world using `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color` can just use the copy-method:

```
val slightlyTransparentRed = Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.9f)
```