# How to get colors?

Tags: android, kotlin, background-color, android-chips

I am trying to achieve something like this

[image]

where the text and background colors are similar. How do I get the corresponding background (probably 50% transparent of chosen color) color for a chip in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply take the color you use for the text and set `alpha` to `0.5f`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I found the possible way programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237614/programmatically-make-a-color-more-transparent

Answer (score 1):

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```

This takes float value ranging from 0.0 (transparent) to 1.0 (fully visible).