# Negative int color value

Tags: java, android, colors, rgb

I have a problem. I have a custom object with fields like

```
private String id;
private int key;
private String name;
private String desc;
private int sortorder;
private int color;
```

And constructor like

```
 public Label(String id, int key, String name, String desc, int sortorder, int color)
```

I'm putting color when creating object like this

```
Color.rgb(dialogColorRed, dialogColorGreen, dialogColorBlue)
```

Where dialogColorRed, dialogColorGreen, dialogColorBlue - are randomly assigned values from 0 to 255.

Then I'm packing an ArrayList of my Objects in JSON, the object looks like this (pay attention to color field)

```
"color": -6508994,
    "desc": "",
    "id": "81fed08a336b185e226a93f199f34803",
    "key": 87,
    "name": "w",
    "sortorder": 0
```

I'm getting negative color int value, but i need something like this

```
 "color":"4278255360"
```

What is the problem?

Comment: how is it that you need something like that? how does that translate into a color?

Comment: Java does not have unsigned ints, and the alpha channel of your color flips the sign bit of the 32-bit int.

Comment: @ItamarGreen this will be transformed by other program. I just need to pack a color like that

Comment: @laalto so what can you recommend?

Comment: Do you actually have a problem that needs to be solved?

Comment: @laalto Yes! :)
I need to convert my negative RGB color into the color "color":"4278255360" this style.
I've watched this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526690/convert-a-raw-negative-rgb-int-value-back-to-a-3-number-rgb-value?rq=1

I don't really get how to get the normal R, G and B and create an Integer from it

Comment: Do you mean `Color.getRGB(dialogColorRed, dialogColorGreen, dialogColorBlue)`? (`getRGB` instead of `rgb`)

Comment: @OleV.V. No. I mean that I'm storing color int with method Color.rgb and if i want to get that color then the program returns me a negative integer. I need to transform this integer into color value "color":"4278255360" - this style. Or another method to store the color

Comment: I still don't see a problem. Negative values will be represented with the same bit pattern representing the same color when parsed back to a 32-bit int.

Comment: Funny. I asked because my `java.awt.Color` class doesn’t have an `rgb` method. Sounds like there’s something I haven’t understood about your question.

Comment: What happens if you just leave the negative value in there and pretend everything is good? Does something go wrong? What?

Comment: Do you need the alpha channel of your colour? If not, you may do `mySignedColorInt & 0xFFFFFF` to obtain a non-negative int that represents your colour.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes. The program can't parse the JSON with such color values.

Comment: @OleV.V. it must be an integer representing ARGB in decimal format (4294967040 → 0xFFFFFF00 → A:FF R:FF G:FF B:00

Comment: Next idea: convert it to a `long`. A Java `int` cannot hold 4294967040, but a `long` can.

Comment: You may also look into `Integer.toUnsignedString(int)`. `Integer.toUnsignedString(-6508994)` yields `4288458302`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi quite late but have you tried,  private long key; instead of private int key;
Explanation : The key you use to store the color code may be bigger than an integer can hold.

The valid range of an Integer variable is -2147483648 through +2147483647.

```
                       2147483647 MAX
```

And you want this number : 4278255360. When an Integer hit the max value, 2147483647 + 1 = -2147483648, it's new value is now the min value.